# How to enable "ctrl+click" with "routerLink" in Angular

Tags: angular, routerlink

In Angular, if you use this:

```
<div routerLink="/home"> <img src="..." /> </div>
```

When I press on image it routes perfect, I want to press ctrl+click to open this link in new tab, or drag this image to a new tab, but when I press ctrl+click it opened in same page, and if I drag it, the image opened in new tab not the link, I tried to use `target="_blank"` but it is not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using a `div` tag, you will need to use an `a` tag so that the browser knows to treat it like a link.

```
<a routerLink="/home"> <img src="..." /> </a>
```

Comment: I tried it with target="_blank" but still not working with ctrl+click

Comment: @MarvinEricson Seems to work when I try it in a StackBlitz. Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the issue?

Comment: but it always opened as a new tab, not just when I press ctrl

Comment: If you have `target="blank"`, then it will always open in a new tab, regardless of whether or not you're pressing ctrl

Answer (score 7):

You can add a `link` role to the div

```html
<div routerLink="/home" role="link">
  <img src="..." /> 
</div>
```

If you want to enable the "ctrl+click" behavior and don't :

- want to change your `div` tag to an `a` tag
- Use `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are facing similar issue mentioned **[`here`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5908)** , i would recommend you to try something like this,

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/home']" ><img src="..." /></a>
```