# How to enable open link in new tab in click event in angular 12

Tags: angular, navigation, router

My click event:

```
html:
 <div class="image"   (click)="onClickOperation(product);">
.......
</div>
TS:
onClickOperation(product: any): void {
    // debugger
    if (this.regularView) {
      if (this.details) {
        this.openLightbox(product);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/product', product.productId]);
      }
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/store', product.shopId]);
      this.productsender.changeMessage(product);
    }
  }
```

its working fine how I want to implement right click to  open link in new tab option .how can I do it need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Routing navigate run in new tab(Use Angular Router naviagte )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50521494/angular-2-routing-navigate-run-in-new-tabuse-angular-router-naviagte), [Angular 2 Routing run in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41355830/8017690)

Comment: What do you mean, right-click to open a new link? did you mean left to on the button?

Comment: right click to open in new tab option @HassanMoin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to be able to open the link via the right-click menu then you need to pass `routerLink` to the `a` tag.
There is the solution: [How to enable "ctrl+click" with "routerLink" in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686140/how-to-enable-ctrlclick-with-routerlink-in-angular)

And an example:

```html
<a routerLink="/user/bob">link to user component</a>
```

or

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/user/jim']">Jim</a>
```

You need "a" tag because in HTML only this tag has the property to open links by HTML functionality.

Information on how to use `routerLink` you can find in angular [routerLink docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description)

In your case probably you should use `*ngIf` make a condition to display a correct element with the correct URL.

There is an example of how to make it. [Conditionally add RouterLink or other attribute directives to an element in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753819/conditionally-add-routerlink-or-other-attribute-directives-to-an-element-in-angu)

If you want to replace the context menu with your function, just look at this issue:
[How to handle right click event in Angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619887/how-to-handle-right-click-event-in-angular-app)